# Getting the Mean by a Factor

Tags: r, subset

All, I wrote this function but it has flaws:

```
X=cbind(rep(1:5,4),rep(c(1,2,4,8,16),2),c(3.4,4,45,6,4,2,36,4,34,7,8,0,2,4,5,7,9,12,23,1))
getXbarl<-function(Y,l){
  xbar=tapply(Y,l,mean)
  return(matrix(xbar[l]))#***
}
#It works for the first row:
getXbarl(X[,3],X[,1])
#but not the second row, because the factors are no longer 1:5 here. 
getXbarl(X[,3],X[,2])
```

Please help me write a fix. The issue is that for xbar[l]***, it no longer corresponds to the index.

Comment: What's your desired output of the function? Specifically, I don't see you are extracting from `xbar`. Or,  rephrase my question: why do you want your second example output to have 15 entries? Also, this code does what you want, but with less code: `aggregate(Y, by= list(l), mean)`

Comment: Oh ok. I came up with a fix below but it is no very eligant. basically I want to have to have a vector that repeats the mean by factor for every x value. If you run it you will see what I mean...

Comment: you get a mean vector the same length as the X vector, so you can subtract them to get the residual. Useful when your professor doesn't want you to use built in R functions

Comment: Your code is close to correct. You could change to `return(matrix(xbar[as.character(l)]))`. Came here from meta. The only important missing piece in your post is the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `ave`

```
ave(X[,3], X[,2])
```

As a function

```
getXbarl2 <- function(Y,l) matrix(ave(Y,l))
identical(getXbarl(X[,3], X[,1]), getXbarl2(X[,3], X[,1]))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! I could have used that function a lot before LOL.

Comment: @Rik No problem.  If you have NAs, consider to change the function as `matrix(ave(Y, l, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
getXbarl<-function(Y,l){
  xbar=tapply(Y,l,mean)
  l2=factor(l,labels=1:length(xbar))
  return(matrix(xbar[l2]))
}
X=cbind(rep(1:5,4),rep(c(1,2,4,8,16),2),c(3.4,4,45,6,4,2,36,4,34,7,8,0,2,4,5,7,9,12,23,1))

getXbarl(X[,3],X[,1])

getXbarl(X[,3],X[,2])
```